# can I create a PDF from ImageMagick which will always open at zoom 100%?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, image-manipulation, png

I am running with an issue in **png to pdf** conversion.Actually I have big png file not in size but in contents.In pdf conversion it create a big pdf file. I don't have any issue with its quality, but whenever I try to open this pdf in PDF viewer, it make it Fit to Page. So, I can't see created PDF in my first view, I need to zoom it upto 100%.

So my question is, can I create a PDF  from ImageMagick which will always open at zoom 100% ?

Or can I set such **zoom property** in PDF while converting png to pdf ?

Thanks.